# Accent and gender issues for Full Text Search postgresql

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, stemming

I got two different inputs that should be stemmed to the same output :

```
SELECT to_tsvector('french', 'fermier'),
       to_tsvector('french', 'fermièr'),
       to_tsvector('french', 'fermiér'),
       to_tsvector('french', 'fermiere'),
       to_tsvector('french', 'fermière'),
       to_tsvector('french', 'fermiére')

-- Output
'fermi':1 'fermier':1 'fermier':1 'fermier':1 'fermi':1 'fermier':1
```

Ignoring accent would be possible but it would still collapse output to two differents options : `fermier` or `fermi`.
For information, the only difference between `fermier` and `fermiere` is the gender, the former is masculine and the latter is feminine.
Thus, issue is that the feminine form is stemmed to the masculine form which is itself stemmed to `fermi`.
I don't understand why stemming is not invariable from gender here.

Comment: Yes, that is odd. I tried to add the `unaccent` dictionary to the configuration, which changed the result, but still stemmed the male and female forms differently. Snowball dictionaries use a heuristic and don't have real knowledge about the language. Perhaps you can try a French [Ispell dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-ISPELL-DICTIONARY), that might give you better results.

Comment: For your [reading pleasure](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/32914d900f90f7f5238a3856e67f6bc5bf05e1d9/src/backend/snowball/libstemmer/stem_UTF_8_french.c#L259)... It looks like the verb conjugation endings are truncated (I know, "fermier" or "dernier" are not exactly verbs... but they look like it :-)